# How to define an user that has same element with current user with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a function that show a recommended user(s) to a new user based on the category that a new user picked.

So recommended user should be user_type: "star" and it has same category.id that a current_user picked.

These are the models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :categorizings, as: :categorizable, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :categories,    through: :categorizings
end

class Categorizing < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :categorizings, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :users, through: :categorizings, source: :categorizable, source_type: 'User'
end
```

And, this is my pseudo coded method to find a recommended user that I'm stuck on...

```
CategoriesController < ApplicationController
 def recommended_user
  @recommended_user = User.where(user_type: 'star' && Who has same category.id with a current_user)
 end
end
```

Sorry for the confusing explanation, but anything helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Should all the categories match, or any in the set?

Comment: do you have `current_user` helper in your app?

Comment: Yes, I do have current_user helper in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@recommended_user = User
                    .joins(:categories)
                    .where(
                      users: { user_type: 'star' },
                      categories: { id: current_user.categories.first.id }
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@recommended_user = User.where(user_type: 'star').where(category_id: current_user.category_id)
```

Comment: user does not belong to category, thus it will not have the `category_id` column